# Equivalent of `MomentConvert` for free moments/free cumulants?

Tags: probability-or-statistics, algebraic-manipulation

I'm looking for Mathematica implementation of conversion between free moments and free cumulants.

For instance, for traditional moments we have from `MomentConvert[Cumulant[3], "Moment"]`

$$c_3=\mu_3-3 \mu _2 \mu _1+2 \mu _1{}^3$$

But for free cumulant $c_3$ we should see

$$c_3 = \mu_3+3\mu_2\mu_1-4\mu_1^3$$

- formulas from 214-215 of Terry Tao's [book](https://terrytao.files.wordpress.com/2011/02/matrix-book.pdf)
- free cumulants allow computing expressions like $E\operatorname{Tr}(XYXY)$ where $X,Y$ are large Gaussian matrices
- related discussion is on [mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/466224/joint-moments-like-tauxyxyxy-in-terms-of-individual-moments-of-free-variabl), specifically Example 14.6 of Speicher [book](https://rolandspeicher.files.wordpress.com/2020/06/nica-speicher-book.pdf)

Comment: In the middle of page 215 of the Tao book you linked, in exercise 2.5.21, I find the formula $C_3(X)=\tau (X^3)-3\tau (X^2) \tau (X)+2\tau (X)^3$. Isn't that equivalent to the result you obtained from `MomentConvert`?

Comment: @MarcoB bottom of page 214 has the other formula, I believe the two formulas got accidentally swapped in the book, since $\mu_3-3 \mu _2 \mu _1+2 \mu _1^3$ is known to be the third cumulant for commuting variables rather than free

Comment: Regarding the close votes, I think it's useful to keep this open because this question is likely to be resolved eventually, and this gives easier searchability. If it's closed, when I find the solution, it'll end up in my private notes instead

Comment: Look in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4410477/free-cumulant-generating-function